# Parsing a Ruby string to extract method names

Tags: regex, ruby, onigmo

I have a string such as

```
str1='f(x)myfunction1("a",1,"b"),f(x)myfunction2("c","d",4),
f(x)myfunction3("e","f","g",3)'
```

I want to write a regex using scan or match where I create an array and extract function names and associated parameters.

```
myFunctionArry[0]='myfunction1("a",1,"b")'
myFunctionArry[1]='myfunction2("c","d",4)'
myFunctionArry[2]='myfunction3("e","f","g",3)'
```

What is the correct way to extract? I tried positive and negative lookaheads, but I am unable to divvy up each function name properly

`str1.scan(/(?<=f\(x\))(.*)(?=\))/)` seems to give me the wrong result.

Comment: You could also write `str1.gsub('f(x)','').split(/(?<=\)),/)`.

Comment: Once you correct the regex you will need to tack on `.flatten` to the end, as `str1.scan /(?<=f\(x\))(.*?\))/ #=> [["myfunction1(\"a\",1,\"b\")"], ["myfunction2(\"c\",\"d\",4)"], ["myfunction3(\"e\",\"f\",\"g\",3)"]]` (the regex taken from @Sergio's answer. Another way: `str1.gsub(/(?<=f\(x\))(.*?\))/).to_a`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right.

Make the `*` non-greedy, and include the closing parenthesis into the match.

```
(?<=f\(x\))(.*?\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/8SEm9G/1

Comment: Sergio, thank you so much, this is exactly, what I needed.

Comment: @muratp: Don't forget to mark this as the answer with the check mark on the left.